# loop with condition ignored by the system in sap abap

Tags: loops, conditional-statements, abap

I try to applied loop with condition to sum up the respective row(field), the where condition should be correct but during running of the system, the program ignored the condition and sum up all rows, any suggestion to fix this problem?

```
SELECT * FROM LIPS INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE LT_LIPS
      WHERE VGBEL = LT_BCODE_I-VGBEL  "getDN number
      AND VGPOS = LT_BCODE_I-VGPOS.    " get vgpos = 01/02/03

  LOOP AT LT_BCODE_I INTO LT_BCODE_I WHERE VGBEL = LT_LIPS-VGBEL AND VGPOS = LT_LIPS-VGPOS.
    SUM.
    LT_BCODE_I-MENGE = LT_BCODE_I-MENGE.
  ENDLOOP
```

.

Comment: ABAP has never had any bug related to loops for 22 years I've been working on. You have several unrelated internal tables that we don't know the contents. Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can tell you what's wrong. You should also focus on either LOOP or SUM topic, not both. Moreover, you don't use [SUM](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapsum.htm) as indicated in the ABAP documentation.

Comment: most likely `LT_LIPS` is a table with [header line](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-us/abenitab_header_line.htm) and here `VGBEL = LT_LIPS-VGBEL` you compare empty structure. The source of your problems is that you use obsolete ABAP elements and do not learn the best practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you are asking about `LOOP`, I think the issue is more about how you use [SUM](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapsum.htm).

> The statement SUM **can only be specified within a loop LOOP** and is only respected **within a AT-ENDAT** control structure.

Here is an excerpt from the ABAP documentation, for *"Calculation of a sum with SUM at AT LAST. All lines of the internal table are evaluated"*:

```
DATA:
  BEGIN OF wa,
    col TYPE i,
  END OF wa,
  itab LIKE TABLE OF wa WITH EMPTY KEY.

itab = VALUE #( FOR i = 1 UNTIL i > 10 ( col = i ) ).

LOOP AT itab INTO wa.
  AT LAST.
    SUM.
    cl_demo_output=>display( wa ).
  ENDAT.
ENDLOOP.
```